# Pause/play and foreword/backward capability for audio files in raspberry pi

Tags: audio

I am looking to play audio files on the Raspberry pi through the standard audio out. I also want to have pause/play and seek foreword/backward functionality. I am currently using pygame to play the wav file but cant seem to include these functionalities.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: what does this mean? `cant seem to include these functionalities`

Comment: I would use the omxplayer wrapper and its seek method. https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/omxplayer/#module-omxplayer.player Similar to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96551/turn-up-or-down-volume-for-omxplayer-3-5mm-audio-jack/96578#96578